# JdbcTokenStore implementation with Spring-Boot and OAuth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-boot

Hej,

I am trying to implement OAuth2 in an Application using Spring-Boot. I am struggling with the implementation of the **JdbcTokenStore** (did I understood this right, that this is to store the Token in the Database?)

My Code looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private TokenStore tokenStore = new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
```

....

```
    @Override
    public void configure(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
         oauthServer.tokenStore(tokenStore).authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
```

Doing this I am getting following error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [se.....config.OAuth2ServerConfig$OAuth2Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f6b9ba94]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource required

The database connection itself seems to work, at least I can login with user data (username / password) stored in the database when I use **InMemoryTokenStore**.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or recommend sources where good examples are for this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410215/spring-boot-rest-service-with-oauth2-security-credentials-from-database/29383551#29383551

Answer (score 1):

That's a basic dependency injection problem (nothing fancy and nothing oauth- or Boot- related). You can't initialize a field from an `@Autowired` (the wiring takes place after initialization). You need to pull that out into a `@PostConstruct` or a `@Bean`.

Comment: The dataSource() is defined in another Configuration Class as a @Bean. I thought that I could access it afterwards with @Autowired?

Comment: You can, but you can't then use it in a field initializer. It's simple to pull the token store creation out into a method.