# Spring Boot Rest service with oAuth2 Security credentials from database

Tags: rest, jpa, oauth-2.0, spring-boot

Could anyone please help me with an example of a Spring Boot application that contains a Rest Service with endpoints protected by Spring Security using oAuth2 with user credentials from a MySQL database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this one: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/tests/annotation/jdbc (it's not MySQL, but it's JDBC, so the transformation is trivial)?

Comment: Thanks Dave. I am still quite new with spring security. Spring boot makes it super easy to create a RESTful service, but I am still unclear with the implementation of security using oAuth2 and database credentials. I saw some pre-Spring Boot projects that creates token and refresh tables in the DB. Is this not the custom anymore? https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth uses in-memory authentication. Is that preferred above storing the tokens in the DB?

Comment: That link contains SQL files for the schema you mentioned (they are executed on startup for the in-memory database, but you could execute them yourself for mysql). Roy's sample is similar (and equally minimal), but an in-memory user store obviously isn't going to be useful in production for most systems.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth/ 
and perform following changes, It uses primary datasource defined in application.properties,

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "rest_api";

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends
            ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/users").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/review").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/logreview").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/oauth/token").authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .csrf()
                    .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
                    .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                    ;
            }

            private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
                return new OncePerRequestFilter() {

                    @Override
                    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                            HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                            throws ServletException, IOException {

                        CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
                                .getName());
                         if (csrf != null) {
                            Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                            String token = csrf.getToken();
                            if (cookie == null || token != null
                                    && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                                cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                                cookie.setPath("/");
                                response.addCookie(cookie);
                            }
                        }
                        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                    }
                };
            }
            private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
                HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
                repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
                return repository;
            }
        }


    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends
            AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {


        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        DataSource dataSource;


        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {

            endpoints
                .tokenStore(new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource))
                .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);

        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients
                .jdbc(dataSource);
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
            DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
            tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
            tokenServices.setAccessTokenValiditySeconds(300);
            tokenServices.setRefreshTokenValiditySeconds(6000);
            tokenServices.setTokenStore(new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource));
            return tokenServices;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am new to this, but for some reasons I doesn't work for POST Requests.

{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?"}

It works fine with GET methods

Comment: got same problem, have you found a solution?